# Electron cannot find module grpc.node

Tags: typescript, electron

when I run my electron app, I get the following error from console and pulling out my hair.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ahmet/Documents/JumbleUp/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/electron-v3.1-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node'
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/ahmet/Documents/JumbleUp/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ahmet/Documents/JumbleUp/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ahmet/Documents/JumbleUp/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:63)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620)
```

Comment: Try to rebuild the grpc module with npm rebuild grpc --force

Comment: unfortunately, still getting the same error, could it be general electron bug of v4.0.4? das macht kein Sinn:)

Comment: Does the specified path exist "/Users/ahmet/Documents/JumbleUp....."?